# r rank sum differs from individual vectors and matrix that consists of these vectors

Tags: r, sum, rank

I have data

```
a1 <- 1:5
b1 <- rep(2,5)
c1 <- c(-1,2,0.5,3.2,0.1)
```

and matrix that consists of these vectors

```
vekt <- c(a1,b1,c1)
```

Now the sum of ranks of vekt is 120:

```
ranksit <- rank(vekt, ties.method = "average")
ranksit
sum(ranksit)
```

However, for the individual vectors the sum of ranks is much larger:

```
ranksit1 <- rank(vekt, ties.method = "average")[vekt == a1]
ranksit1
sum(ranksit1)

ranksit2 <- rank(vekt, ties.method = "average")[vekt == b1]
ranksit2
sum(ranksit2)

ranksit3 <- rank(vekt, ties.method = "average")[vekt == c1]
ranksit3
sum(ranksit3)
```

The sum of these is (69+56+43) 168. I notice that the length of these (ranksit 1-3) are larger by 2 elements so some values appear in them twice.

Why is this and how the issue could be addressed?

Comment: may i suggest that you study `vekt == a1` very carefully? i.e. how many TRUEs are there and how many TRUEs are you expecting?

Comment: Thanks, issue solved. Replaced ```vekt == a1``` respectively with ```1:length(a1)``` ... and so on.